# How do I set the scope of this MySQL UPDATE operation?

Tags: mysql

**Standard disclaimer:** I'm a total know-nothing when it comes to MySQL. The way I'm trying to do things is almost certainly not clever, and I'm open to suggestions for improvement.

I have two databases: `wordpress` and `wordpress3`. `wordpress3` is a copy of `wordpress`, converted to UTF-8. In the process of conversion, however, mis-encoded characters caused data loss.

### My Goal:

1. Locate all entries in `wordpress.wp_options` where the `option_value` when encoded as UTF-8 is not the same as when encoded as ASCII.
2. For each entry described by #1 above, update the corresponding entries in `wordpress3.wp_options` with the data from `wordpress`, converted to UTF-8.

I'm checking and replacing the `option_values` column of `wp_options` right now as a proof of concept. Once I get it working, I want to rejigger the thing so that it does this for all columns in all tables in the database... but that's getting ahead of myself.

### My Script:

```
update wordpress3.wp_options wp3
    SET wp3.option_value = (SELECT
        CONVERT(wp.option_value using UTF8) from wordpress.wp_options wp
        WHERE convert(wp.option_value using ascii) != convert(wp.option_value using utf8)
        AND wp.option_id = wp3.option_id)
    WHERE [?]
```

### My Issue:

I don't know how to write the WHERE statement for the UPDATE command (hence the [?]). With nothing in that WHERE statement, my script will match and update seven rows the way I want them updated... but then `wp3.option_value` will be set to NULL for everything that doesn't match the subquery.

I can define the WHERE explicitly, by using `option_name`s for options I know need to be replaced, like so:

```
WHERE wp3.option_name = 'shortcoder_data';
```

...but that's slow and clunky.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `INNER JOIN` to join the two tables (`wordpress.wp_options wp` and `wordpress3.wp_options wp3`) and select only the entries where `wp.option_id` and `wp3.option_id` were the same, but `convert(wp.option_value using ascii)` and `convert(wp.option_value using utf8)` were different:

```
UPDATE wordpress3.wp_options wp3
INNER JOIN wordpress.wp_options wp ON (wp.option_id = wp3.option_id
    AND convert(wp.option_value using utf8) != convert(wp.option_value using ascii))
SET wp3.option_value = convert(wp.option_value using utf8);
```

This seems to have done the trick.